# what should server do when user open a sub page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, web

I'm developing a web server but I'm a newbie so I have a basic question.

Imagine that on the index page, there are many countries. If user clicks on some country, a new page should be opened. Obviously the content of new pages depends on the clicked country.

For example, the url of index page is: www.mysite.com
When I click on France, the url of new page is: www.mysite.com/France

I just want to know that what should the server do in this case.
I mean when user clicks France, the server receives the string `France`, then what should it do? Need it generate a whole new page? Or it just need to send the message to the page France.html so that user can visit the new page? If so I'm considering that I need to create many new pages because I have more than 150 countries...

Is it possible to generate only one page, which can take messages coming from the server and show them?

Comment: Well if you had 150 pages one for each country - that would be pretty counter intuitive - not to mention a pain to maintain. The process to fetch a dynamic page and "hard-coded" page is almost the same. This will help: http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/ - You can have one page "Countries.cshtml" passing in a countryId that will load the country by id. How have you got over 1.5k in points haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to solve your problem, you'll have to decide which one suits you better.

**JavaScript Approach**

1. User clicks on France
2. A javascript function re-generates the page so that everything is shown in French

With this simple method you can have one single html page, but you'll have to code the "web re-generation process".

**PHP Approach**

1. User clicks on France
2. Your PHP receives "France" and sends back the French Html page

But of course you'll need to code a Html page for every country.